# SLAPD Fails to Open TLS Certificate

Tags: linux, ldap, tls

I am trying to configure TLS for SLAPD, but it keeps failing with the error "TLS init def ctx failed". I was able to trace the error to the system call where the daemon tries to open the CA certificate file (`open("/etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES`). It opens the CRT file with the O_RDONLY flag and gets EACCES as the response. However, the file itself is world readable. Furthermore, I ran `sudo -u openldap cat /etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt` and the file outputs just fine (openldap is indeed the user and group of the daemon). Any advice?

EDIT:

Permissions on file are 644 owned by root:root, and permissions on all parent directories are 755 owned by root:root. I tried changing owner/group to openldap and also tried changing permissions to 777. Also tried moving the file to /, all with no luck. Also tried running as root, i.e., running without the -u and -g options, and it still fails.

Last lines of strace output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1147299/

Comment: Can you post a few lines of `strace` output?  Are you certain `slapd` is running as the `openldap` user?  Can you show us the permissions on both `/etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt` and /etc/ssl/certs`?  Can you show us the TLS-related portions of your `slapd.conf`?

Comment: Are you sure it is failing only for the CA certificate? What about the Server certificate and it's key?
Could you paste your slapd.conf and ls -l of your certificates?

Comment: Added requested info to the question. Also, it does not seem to even be attempting to open the other files once it fails to open the CA cert file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) is probably denying access to the file, check `/var/log/kern.log` to confirm this:

```
grep audit /var/log/kern.log
```

If this is the case, edit `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.slapd` and give it permission to this file.

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ r,
/etc/ssl/certs/* r,
```

Run `sudo service apparmor reload` after modifying the profiles.

Comment: This was indeed the case. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Unfortunately, slapd is now giving me other troubles. :P

Answer (score 2):

This smells a lot like SELinux or some other security module.  Is selinux enabled?  You can look in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for messages indicating that selinux has blocked an operation.  You can also try disabling selinux by running:

```
# setenforce 0
```

And now start up `slapd`.  If it works, this was your problem, and there are two ways to fix it:

- Persistently disable selinux.  Exactly how to do this depends on your distribution.
- Create an selinux policy that will allow slapd to read from the certificate.

You can use the `audit2allow` program to [generate an appropriate selinux policy](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html).

See mgorven's answer for what to do if you've got AppArmor instead of SElinux.